# Could not create Java EE project in NetBeans in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, jdk, netbeans

When I open NetBeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 this error appears.

[image: image of the error]

I have both NetBeans 8.1 and NetBeans 8.2 versions installed and I have 3 different versions of JDKs installed. I have given the correct JDK path in "netbeans.conf" and "/etc/profile", but I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have the EE JDK installed?

Comment: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   " ,"     
            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java    " , "
       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java " , "
          /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   "       
@FireFaced I have installed the above java versions. Do I need to install any other ??

Comment: I'm unsure. You mentioned EE in the title though.

Comment: The reason for this problem was that I have not given the correct jdk path in the NetBeans installation. I completely uninstall it and again install it by giving the correct jdk path. Then it works.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Please put that in an answer and accept it so that people know it's solved.